# XNA Visual Studios 2010 unusual deploy errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

Recently, I've been having 3 unusual errors when I try to deploy my projects. I know XNA is basically obsolete, but I started this game a long time ago and I want to finish it using XNA. I can't deploy on the WP7 emulator or on any device. I'm running on W8.1. I've worked on the same project for a while, on the same OS, and had no problems. But all of a sudden, I started having these errors. I didn't really change anything significant on the recent changes I made. These are the errors.

> 1) The "FilesToFilter=@(ReferenceSatellitePaths)" parameter for the
>   "FilterItemsBySupportedCultures" task is invalid.
>
> 2) The "FilterItemsBySupportedCultures" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.ArgumentException: Object of type
>   'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]' cannot be converted to type
>   'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]'.    at
>   System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo
>   culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)    at
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters,
>   Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature
>   sig)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object
>   value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index,
>   CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object
>   value, Object[] index)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.TaskFactoryWrapper.SetPropertyValue(ITask
>   task, TaskPropertyInfo property, Object value)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.InternalSetTaskParameter(TaskPropertyInfo
>   parameter, Object parameterValue)
>
> 3)The "FilterItemsBySupportedCultures" task could not be initialized
>   with its input parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `VS 2010 Express` for Windows Phone you needed to edit the file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VPDExpress.exe.config`

Add this at the very top of bindings after probing tag

`<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>`

Worked for me. Works with installed VS2013 and VS2015.

P.S.
You need to edit file on the desktop to have the permission to write file and then copy it to the needed location.

Comment: Works for me (improvising a bit and applying to vs2010 ultimate's devenv.exe.config. My problem wasn't XNA related but a similar bug with ITaskItem). 

In case it helps anyone, I think the bug cropped up around the time I updated vs2015 from an early version to update 3. But I can't be 100% sure. New .net and .net core may have come onto my system at that time.  

The 12.0.0.0-14.0.0.0 part was crucial. It looks like devenv was using multiple different msbuild versions at different times and the range was necessary to catch them all.

Answer (score 3):

By all symptoms it's a sort of version conflict after installing update, new Framework version or VS. Maybe I found [solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/481044fb-b448-4ce2-8518-65432dcd0320/multiple-errors-at-after-creation-of-project) to your problem:

1. Edit file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`
2. Add the following block into the bindings block in this file:

   `<dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>`

I'm not sure if author really meaned `Microsoft Visual Studio **10.0**` in the path (because 11.0 is VS2012).

Comment: I'm currently having this problem on VS2010. Yesterday I downloaded 2012 and I'm going to see if I can deploy my project through there.

Comment: @chelo666 well, have you tried to apply same fix for a VS2010? Apply fixes to file in `... 10.0` folder.